# Value not retained in the dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I am using the simple form in my application where I have a drop down. The code is as:

```
<%= f.select :assigned_to, options_for_select(@user_members.collect{ |u| [u.name,u.id] }, :selected =>"#{@task.assigned_to}"),  :prompt => "Assign To"%>
```

The issue that I am facing is that the value is not retained in the drop down after refreshing the page even though I have used :selected also.

Comment: How do you persist the choice?

Comment: The value in the drop down is updated on the select of any value. But if I refresh the page then the value doesn't persist.

Comment: You mean, updated on a screen? That's nothing. You have to save it to database as well.

Comment: Yes it is updated in the database when we select any value from the dropdown

Comment: (1.4ms)  UPDATE "tasks" SET "assigned_to" = 4, "updated_at" = '2013-11-07 12:13:36.304687' WHERE "tasks"."id" = 6
   (27.8ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered tasks/update_assigned_to.js.erb (0.4ms)

Comment: why are you generating a string from the `assigned_to` method?

Comment: replace `"{@task.assigned_to}"` with `@task.assigned_to` and have a look on this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/20243283/railshow-to-create-dynamic-drop-down-box-in-rails/20244284#20244284

Comment: @gopal Had done that also earlier but that didn't work

Comment: Had done "{@task.assigned_to.name}" but it didn't work.... then I did "{@task.assigned_to.id}" and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

The selected field's value should be pased in the params, so you can use that as the selected. Use the "pry" gem to debugg, your development life will become much easier :)

Try that and let me know how it went. Also, could you the code from your controller?

Comment: My controller code:                                                 def update_assigned_to
    @task = Task.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(assigned_to: User.find_by_id(params[:task][:assigned_to]))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

Comment: Can some help me out in this?

Comment: The relevant HTML code genarated is as: <select id="task_assigned_to" name="task[assigned_to]"><option value="7">snehaa</option>
<option value="8">sjdhfksjdhf</option></select>

Comment: I am not getting selected="selected" even after putting :selected =>"#{@task.assigned_to}" in my code

Comment: In your simple form try something like this:

f.input :assigned_to, collection: @user_members.map{|u| [u.name,u.id]}, :selected =>"#{@task.assigned_to}")  

IF @task.assigned_to is in your collection it should be selected (as expected).